# Setting baselayer transparency in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

In arcgis we can set baselayer transparency according to use how to do same in qgis

Comment: Seems odd to set base layer transparency, since it is at the bottom by definition what layers will you see beneath it?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the QuickMapServices plugin and use QGIS Version 2.xx you can simply double click(or right click and go to properties) on a base map and set the transparency as needed.

[image: Screenshot of QGIS with properties of a baselayer from QMS open]

When using Openlayers Plugin you can go to the transparency tab in the properties and change the value.

[image: transparency in Openlayer Plugin]

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18. In that I am working with open layer plugin. Whenever I try to open the property of Google Street map, it says this layer doesn't have property dialog.

Comment: @juhiacharya use QuickMapServices, OpenLayers does not support that functionality. Or use XYZ tile layers.